# Use an PHP Array and JSON to Create a Navigation List?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a Javascript ajax function that calls a PHP page to run a query and return an array of values which I then want to use to build a navigation list.

I can retrieve the results from the query, add them to an array and then encode them using json_encode but when they are returned to the ajax function I'm having problems extracting the values from the array and building the nav list.

Any help is very much appreciated.

My PHP Code is:

```
<?php

require_once("../includes/functions.inc");

$access_id = $_POST['access_id'];

$mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    error_log("Cannot connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    return false;
}

$query = "SELECT nav_link, nav_icon, nav_name FROM tbl_nav WHERE access_id <= " . $access_id;

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

My Javascript code is

```
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'php_files/user_process/left_nav_generate.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                access_id: sessionStorage.getItem('access_id')
            },
            success: function(data) {

                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var headerNavItem = '';

                var navBarList = '';
                var footerNavItem = '';

                headerNavItem = '<ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">';
                headerNavItem += '<li><a href="dashboard.html"><i class="icon-home"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>';
                headerNavItem += '<li class="navigation-divider"></li>';

                for (var i in obj) {

                    navBarList = '<li><a href="' + data[i].nav_link;
                    navBarList += '"><i class="' + data[i].nav_icon;
                    navBarList += '"></i> <span>' + data[i].nav_name;
                    navBarList += '</span></a></li>';

                }

                footerNavItem = '</ul>';

                document.getElementById('leftNav').innerHTML = headerNavItem + navBarList + footerNavItem;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: With `dataType: 'JSON',` your `data` argument is already a json, there's no need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: SQL injection warning comes here.

Comment: If there's an alternate way to produce the access id, I would suggest letting a backend process invoke the PHP to produce a flat JSON file at regular intervals (cron).  Then have the PHP code pull in the flat JSON with `file_get_contents` or use jquery method "getJSON" http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_assoc since you will use each record as an object later, and make a few corrections in your javascript (I commented them):

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            access_id: sessionStorage.getItem('access_id')
        },
        success: function(data) {

            var obj = data; // JSON.parse(data); -> is not needed
            var headerNavItem = '';

            var navBarList = '';
            var footerNavItem = '';

            headerNavItem = '<ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">';
            headerNavItem += '<li><a href="dashboard.html"><i class="icon-home"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>';
            headerNavItem += '<li class="navigation-divider"></li>';

            for (var i in obj) {

                // added concatenation from the start
                // otherwise your list will always have just one line
                navBarList += '<li><a href="' + data[i].nav_link;
                navBarList += '"><i class="' + data[i].nav_icon;
                navBarList += '"></i> <span>' + data[i].nav_name;
                navBarList += '</span></a></li>';

            }

            footerNavItem = '</ul>';

            document.getElementById('leftNav').innerHTML = headerNavItem + navBarList + footerNavItem;
        }
    });
});
```

And as commented, to avoid SQL injection is a good practice to convert the id to integer (or whatever the type of the access_id field in database):

```
$access_id = (int)$_POST['access_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. According to u_mulder's comment: Your `data` argument is already a `JSON` so remove `JSON.parse(data);`.
2. `navBarList = '<li><a href="' + data[i].nav_link;` The `navBarList` variable  restarts for every item every item in the `for` statement. Change it to `navBarList += '<li><a href="' + data[i].nav_link;`.
3. You can use a simple variable to build your HTML navigation list.

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var obj = [{
    "nav_link": "nav_link1",
    "nav_icon": "nav_icon1",
    "nav_name": "Name 1"
  }, {
    "nav_link": "nav_link2",
    "nav_icon": "nav_icon2",
    "nav_name": "Name 2"
  }, {
    "nav_link": "nav_link3",
    "nav_icon": "nav_icon3",
    "nav_name": "Name 3"
  }];

  var html = '<ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">';
  html += '<li><a href="dashboard.html"><i class="icon-home"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>';
  html += '<li class="navigation-divider"></li>';
  for (var i in obj) {
    html += '<li><a href="';
    html += obj[i].nav_link;
    html += '"><i class="';
    html += obj[i].nav_icon;
    html += '"></i> <span>';
    html += obj[i].nav_name;
    html += '</span></a></li>';
  }
  html += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('leftNav').innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="leftNav"></div>
```

Hope this helps.